# Как преобразовать double в объект класса?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, конструктор

По заданию требуется преобразовать double в объект класса. Почему при компиляции выбивает ошибку Stack Overflow?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>
using namespace std;
class MassDouble
{
private:
    double doubleznach;

public:
    MassDouble() {
        double znach = 1.0;
    }
    MassDouble(double X) {
        static_cast<MassDouble>(X); //Тут ошибка Stack Overflow.
    } 
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    MassDouble test(2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Почему бы просто не написать `doubleznach = X;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
MassDouble(double X) {
    static_cast<MassDouble>(X); //Тут ошибка Stack Overflow.
```

Конечно - ведь вы пытаетесь вызвать тот же конструктор для приведения типа...

Я, конечно, не знаю, что именно вы хотите, но большое у меня подозрение, что вам надо это

```
MassDouble() {
    double znach = 1.0;
}
MassDouble(double X) {
    static_cast<MassDouble>(X); //Тут ошибка Stack Overflow.
}
```

заменить на

```
MassDouble(double X = 1.0): doubleznach(X) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Необходим конструктор вида

```
MassDouble(double mass)
{
  doubleznach = mass;
}
```

или

```
MassDouble(double mass) : doubleznach(mass){}
```

если нужен конструктор с двумя параметрами тогда необходимо чтобы один из двух параметров был по умолчанию, он имеет следующий вид

```
MassDouble(int mass1, double mass2 = 1.0);
```

2. Для того что бы преобразовать базовый тип в объект класса необходимо

```
int main()
{
  MassDouble myMass;
  myMass = 5.2;
}
```

Более подробно описанно в книге Прата в 11 главе